# Connecting points in a plane

Tags: python, points, plane

I have a 101x101 array filled with 0's and 1's. If I plot it using matplotlib, it does not connect all the randomly scattered points in a plane.

Just wondering whether there is any python package that connects all the points in a plane. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean "connects all the points in a plane"?

Comment: Do you mean building a Delaunay triangulation? a solution of the TSP (Travelling Salesman Problem)? A complete Kn graph? Which point should be connected to which one?

Comment: @tnknepp: Previous point should be connected to the next subsequent point so that they form some shape

Comment: Do you mean like a surface/contour plot? http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/contourf3d_demo2.html

Comment: What is the sequence of points when the input is a 101×101 boolean matrix? I guess the positions of either the `0`s or the `1`s determine the positions of the points on a 101×101 grid ...

Comment: If you extract the coordinates of the entries containing 1, you can feed that directly to the plot command (matplotlib). But as stated above, only you can decide on the sequence.